# Ассемблер и команды SSE

Tags: ассемблер

Пытаюсь экспериментировать с написанием ассемблерных вставок для приложения с использованием SSE и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

На вики написано, что SSE на данный момент существует несколько версий:
SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2. Так вот в 90% источников, которые я находил в гугле, все команды SSE2 и выше приписываются к группе SSE2. В результате сложно определить, будут ли они поддерживаться каким-нибудь не очень современным процессором или нет.

Например: pxor относится к MMX, но с версии SSE4.1 она начала работать со 128-битными регистрами xmm. 
[Ещё один пример](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-5477/epmpv.html): PSUBQ - насколько я понял, она тоже относится к версии 4.1, но почему-то в списке SSE2.

Вопрос: где можно посмотреть, какие команды к какой точно версии SSE относятся?

Comment: Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals посмотрите. Вряд ли будет что-то полнее...

Comment: Да, там нормально рассортировано, спасибо.